# The relation of mysql insert count to disk io write count

Tags: mysql, insert, io, count

I insert records into the table which storage engine is myISAM. The mysql insert count('Com_insert') is about 8000 per second, but when I run the command 'iostat -dkx 1', the result is:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util

sda             0.00  1322.00  0.00 16.00     0.00  5352.00   669.00     0.59   36.62   5.44   8.70
```

The sum of wrqm/s and w/s is about 1400, which is much less than 8000('Com_insert' count), why?

I think the count of mysql insert should be approximately equal to the sum count of disk's merge write and real write, right or wrong?

Thanks in advance!

------------------------------------ Updated ------------------------------

I insert records one by one, not bulk insert:

```
insert into test(c1,c2,c3,c4) values(1,1,1,'a');
insert into test(c1,c2,c3,c4) values(1,1,1,'a');
insert into test(c1,c2,c3,c4) values(1,1,1,'a');
insert into test(c1,c2,c3,c4) values(1,1,1,'a');
insert into test(c1,c2,c3,c4) values(1,1,1,'a');
insert into test(c1,c2,c3,c4) values(1,1,1,'a');
insert into test(c1,c2,c3,c4) values(1,1,1,'a');
insert into test(c1,c2,c3,c4) values(1,1,1,'a');
insert into test(c1,c2,c3,c4) values(1,1,1,'a');
insert into test(c1,c2,c3,c4) values(1,1,1,'a');
```

...

The table test is myISAM table. Will myISAM engine buffer and merge these insert operations?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can make any such direct relationship or if anyone can suggest either way without knowing a great deal more about the underlying hardware or how the database schedules its own writes, or even optimizes its own I/O. There's all manner of bus bandwidth, latency, write caching, and a billion or so other factors that have to be factored into a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to keep in mind, even without diving into the specifics of MySQL.

Inserts of records are done on pages.  Generally, there is more than one row per page.  So, if you are inserting multiple rows in the same transaction, the page only has to be written once, when it has been filled.

Then, you have the issue of the log and dirty pages.  Even with separate transactions, the changes are logged.  This allows the database to delay writing the page . . . and perhaps another insert will take place.

Then, you have the issue of indexes.  Indexes also need to be written and logged.  This would generally increase the I/O.

I do not know if your count of the I/Os is taking into account the log and indexes.  However, I would venture a guess that you are inserting multiple rows at the same time into a table that has few indexes.